# How to troubleshoot Network Connect issues?

Tags: network, vpn

I have to use Juniper's Network Connect to use my company's VPN.  I haven't changed anything on my system in the past few days, but suddenly Network Connect fails to connect to the VPN with the following error message:

[image]

The log shows the following:

```
2013-03-20 11:38:35.675 ncproxyd[p298.t1799] ipsec.info New tunnel being created (tunnel.cpp:52) 
2013-03-20 11:38:35.681 ncproxyd[p298.t1799] routeutils.info Creating Desktop route table iterator (routeutils.cpp:289)
```

I have tried to uninstall Network Connect, remove all of the files that NC leaves on my system (documented [here](http://www.juniperforum.com/index.php?topic=18091.0)), and reinstall.  I've removed my wifi connection, rebooted, and readded it.  I've mixed these.

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 and Network Connect 7.1.  I'm at a loss.  How can I get my VPN working again?

### Edited on 2013-11-07 to add:

I'm now on 10.9 and still experiencing this issue.  My company's IT reports that there are several other Mac users across various versions of OS X who are having the same issue.  They haven't been able to figure out what is going on.  My company has a backup VPN from another provider, and those of us impacted by this issue have been placed on it.

Comment: so what does the log viewer shows?

Comment: Nothing terribly useful:

2013-03-20 11:38:35.675 ncproxyd[p298.t1799] ipsec.info New tunnel being created (tunnel.cpp:52)
2013-03-20 11:38:35.681 ncproxyd[p298.t1799] routeutils.info Creating Desktop route table iterator (routeutils.cpp:289)

Comment: Have you confirmed if anything has changed on your work's firewall or network?

Comment: I am sure you have read this; http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB9216

Comment: Nothing has changed on my office's firewall or network.

I did find that KB article, but (a) I don't use a firewall on my machine, and (b) that KB article is for Network Connect on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Junos Pulse](https://download.juniper.net/software/pulse/3.0x/b25005/j-pulse-mac-3.0r4-b25005-installer.dmg) instead? At the very least it seems to be better at reporting errors.